# [Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x201ca7a0

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not getting this crash on which line while run app in device. Its just displaying "[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x201ca7a0" in log. But the same build working fine in simulator.I have enabled zombies also. Please help ...

Comment: Show the code where the crash happens.

Comment: Check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081418/xcode-exc-bad-access-not-a-type-retain

Comment: Please provide some more details about the crash that taking place on your app.

Comment: I am not getting  where its crashes in code. please tell me how to know that crash in code.

Comment: thanks erik, but i am not able to get where it is crashing in code. please let me know any techniques to identify crashes in code. I have enabled zombies. My code is working in simulator not in device.

Comment: Put an exception breakpoint and check.

Comment: i had put. but it is showing stack trace. I am not getting any thing from stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace also?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `ARC` on your `fileClass.m` here my post how to:

[Disable ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702604/ios-arc-property-readwrite-nonatomic-vs-radwrite-retain-nonatomic/17389952#17389952)

With `ARC` all obj is always **RETAINED**, so you can remove a part of code `retain`, and on the `IBoutlet` use like this: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet`

Hope this help you